# Scraping data using Python dynamic a table

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use Python to scrape dynamic stock information from a Arabian website :

https://www.boursakuwait.com.kw/ar/securities/prices-and-screens/market-watch

However, I am a newer to Python. So can someone give me a hand for this? Thanks so much.

All I wanna do is scraping the HTML dynamic data from the above website.

i try hard alot of codes and this is the last and give me some data

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.boursakuwait.com.kw/ar/securities/prices-and-screens/market-watch")
time.sleep(20)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
links = driver.find_element_by_id('table-1-1-1-11')
data = links.text

print(data)
```

and it give me some data but not numbers in the table in the website

```
حجم التداول
التغير%
التغير
السعر الحالي
حجم العرض
العرض
حجم الطلب
الطلب
أدنى
أعلى
إفتتاح
السابق
الفترة
الاسم
اسم السهم
رقم السهم



0
0
0.00
0.000
٠
0
٠
0
٠
٠
٠
٠
٠
اقفال اليوم
بنك الكويت الوطني
وطني
101



0
0
0.00
0.000
٠
0
٠
0
٠
٠
٠
٠
٠
اقفال اليوم
بنك الخليج ش.م.ك.ع
خليج ب
102



0
0
0.00
0.000
٠
0
٠
0
٠
٠
٠
٠
٠
اقفال اليوم
بنك الكويت الدولي
الدولي
106



0
```

[this is the table i want from the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEBt8.jpg)

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: thank you for advice i edit it plz help me if you can

Comment: It appears that a  simple `get` operation is s  not  what  fetches the data from the web site.  You need to consult the site documentation for this, tooo see what format they use for  the displayed information.

Comment: i need to but data in xlsx after extract it

Comment: Well, then, you need to use input for the file format you have.  Look up the `csv` package. 
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: first i need to get table data as pd data frame plz

Comment: Yes, you do.  I told you where to find the information.  If you're not willing to do the basic research, read the documentation, and apply the packages designed to handle you're problem, there is little we can do to help you.